# ORACLE MAX GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, left-join

I am using Oracle (SQL Developer). Please find below the example and an outcome which would like to get (purpose of select is to find out people who submitted project A and have not done any activities in project B yet):

Data table:

```
CREATE TABLE "XXX"."TABLE1" 
   (    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "PROJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "PERSON" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ); 
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','A','0','PETER');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','A','0','JOHN');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','A','1','JOHN');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('NEW','A','2','JOHN');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','A','0','MARY');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','B','0','PETER');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('NEW','B','1','PETER');
Insert into XXX.TABLE1 (STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,PERSON) values ('SUBMITTED','B','0','JOHN');
```

Created table should look like this:

```
TABLE1:
TABLE1.STATUS   TABLE1.PROJECT_NAME TABLE1.VERSION_NUMBER   TABLE1.PERSON
SUBMITTED       A                   0                       PETER
SUBMITTED       A                   0                       JOHN
SUBMITTED       A                   1                       JOHN
NEW             A                   2                       JOHN
SUBMITTED       A                   0                       MARY
SUBMITTED       B                   0                       PETER
NEW             B                   1                       PETER
SUBMITTED       B                   0                       JOHN
```

Result what I want get is this:

```
STATUS     PROJECT_NAME  VERSION_NUMBER PERSON  STATUS_1    PROJECT_NAME_1  VERSION_NUMBER_1  PERSON_1
SUBMITTED  A             0              PETER   NEW         B               1                 PETER
SUBMITTED  A             1              JOHN    SUBMITTED   B               0                 JOHN
SUBMITTED  A             0              MARY
```

Select which I am using now is:

```
select  t.*,v.*
from TABLE1 t
left outer join ( select u.*
    from TABLE1 u
where exists (select max(z.VERSION_NUMBER) 
,z.PERSON
,z.PROJECT_NAME
    from TABLE1 z
    where z.PROJECT_NAME = 'B'
    and u.PROJECT_NAME = z.PROJECT_NAME
    and u.PERSON = z.PERSON
group by z.PERSON, z.PROJECT_NAME
having  u.VERSION_NUMBER = max(z.VERSION_NUMBER))) v
on t.PERSON = v.PERSON
where exists (select max (w.VERSION_NUMBER)
,w.PERSON
,w.PROJECT_NAME
from TABLE1 w  
where w.PROJECT_NAME = 'A'
and w.STATUS = 'SUBMITTED'
and t.PROJECT_NAME = w.PROJECT_NAME
and t.PERSON = w.PERSON
group by w.PERSON, w.PROJECT_NAME
having t.VERSION_NUMBER = max (w.VERSION_NUMBER))
```

QUESTION: What would be best(right) way to write such select (best practice), should I better use Analytic functions or use something else instead of EXISTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've over-complicated this...

```
WITH 
 project_status (status, project_name, version_number, person)
 AS
 (SELECT 'SUBMITTED','A','0','PETER' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUBMITTED','A','0','JOHN' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUBMITTED','A','1','JOHN' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NEW','A','2','JOHN' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUBMITTED','A','0','MARY' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUBMITTED','B','0','PETER' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NEW','B','1','PETER' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUBMITTED','B','0','JOHN' FROM dual 
 )  
SELECT DISTINCT
 ps.person
,ps.project_name
,ps.status
FROM
 project_status    ps
WHERE 1=1
AND ps.project_name = 'A'
AND ps.status = 'SUBMITTED'
AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1
  FROM project_status    ps2
  WHERE ps2.person = ps.person
  AND ps2.project_name = 'B'
 )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

> purpose of select is to find out people who submitted project A and
>   have not done any activities in project B yet

If your purpose is just to get the *people*, then you don't need the complete rows.  One method to answer this is to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t1.person
from "XXX"."TABLE1" t1
group by t1.person
having sum(case when project_name = 'A' and status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when project_name = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you need the complete rows, then Christian has a reasonable solution.